# Partial deletion in master detail relationship

Tags: master-detail

In a master-detail relationship, if I am deleting the parent record,lets assume half of its child records were deleted after which I was getting some exception and the remaining child records were not deleted. So in this case, whether the child records which were deleted will it be rolled-back?

Comment: Deleting the master will delete all of it's children automatically by the platform. What do you mean half deletion?

Comment: Like if half of the child records were deleted and then if any exception occurs, what will happen to those deleted records?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are performing the delete operation.

- If you are deleting records with `delete <list of child records>` and if any errors occurs then no records will get deleted. Basically, it is treated as **all or none**
- If you are deleting with `Database.delete(<list of child records>, false)` where `false` allows partial deletion then those records will not get rollback which are not throwing as errors.
- If you are deleting with `Database.delete(<list of child records>, true)` and if any error occurs then all will be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you're using the cascade deletion feature, all records will be deleted without validation or triggers. The only way it can fail is a master record has about 50,000 children, and this will be an automatic roll back. In a more general sense, Salesforce automatically rolls back a transaction if any record therein fails to insert/update/delete/undelete. Obviously, in cases of developers writing code, they can override this behavior, but the default behavior is to automatically roll back in the case of an exception.